# Css Navbar behind the content (z-index doesn't work)

Tags: html, css

I have a Navbar on the right side of the website. But the navbar is behind the Content. I tried z-index: 1000; bit it doesn't works. I also tried to set the z-index of the content on 0. Can anybody say me what I do wrong?

DEMO:

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(29, 183, 255);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(156, 156, 156);
    z-index: 1000;
}

.logo{
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <h4>Logo</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Über Mich</a></li>
        <li><a href="leistungen.html">Leistungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="Referenzen.html">Referenzen</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello @Colin Are your content and nav on the same level or is one of them embeded in another div ?

Comment: they're in different divs

Comment: So you have to change the z-index of the parent they are in I would say

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a position like `position: relative;`

Here's the code:

```
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(29, 183, 255);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(156, 156, 156);
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: ah thnks it works. but the position tag hav to be above the z-index

Comment: @Colin I have looked at the code and everything works fine as you described it. If you want to have something specific then please describe your problem in more detail

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` does ***not*** work on the default position which is `position: static`, you should change it to `position: relative` or  any other positions (absolute, fixed, or sticky)

```css
 nav{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(29, 183, 255);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(156, 156, 156);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your div are not on the same level `z-index` wont affect them
try changing the parent's z-index

```css
.p {
height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff000070;
  display: flex;
justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  z-index: 1;
}
.second-parent {
  margin-top: -200px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  height: 90%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: purple;
}
.second-child {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="p parent">
Parent
  <div class="child">
child</div>
</div>
<div class="p second-parent">
Second Parent
  <div class="second-child">
Second Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
position : fixed;
top : 0px;
```

in css of nav. Like this

```
nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 8vh;
            background-color: rgb(29, 183, 255);
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgb(156, 156, 156);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
        }
```

By doing this your content will hide behind navbar for solving this just add padding-top to your content.
Hope it helps ☺